# How to update JTextFields in a GridLayout?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextfield, paintcomponent

I have a `MainPanel` which uses the `Gridlayout`. Consequently I have created four `JPanel` classes for the: NORTH, EAST, CENTER and EAST layouts respectively. I then add all four to my `MainPanel`.

However, on my WEST panel I use another grid layout to store `JButtons` and `JTextFields`. I want to constantly update my `JTextFields` as they display a value (that changes when a button on another panel is clicked). How do I allow that value to be changed when the `JFrame` is running?

I tried using `paintComponent`, but it keeps on adding multiple copies of the same `JTextField` after each other, as I add it in my `paintComponent` method. If I remove the add method the values won't update.

Comment: Do you have the code?  Generally, though, in Swing, there is very little reason to override paintComponent unless you are creating your own widget.

Comment: Can't really upload code as it is part of an assignment

Comment: I guess you mean BorderLayout. What do you mean by "update a JTextField"? Change its text? If so, just call the `setText()` method.

Comment: the value displays a number from another class, so it gets the value from the field in that class. This value is constantly changing, so new values won't update on my panel once the frame is running

Comment: Can you upload a small subset of code that is compilable and highlights the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: @JB Nizet Issue resolved, it was just that I needed to call `setText()` in my paint method.

Comment: *"I needed to call setText() in my paint method."*  That sounds suspiciously like something you should ***never*** do.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) works well to encapsulate such functionality. In the example below, a number of text fields listen for an `ActionEvent` received from a single <kbd>Update</kbd> button. The common `UpdateHandler` is derived from `AbstractAction`.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14947144/230513 */
public class Test {

    private JButton button = new JButton("Update");

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(createPanel(button), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.add(createPanel(button), BorderLayout.WEST);
        f.add(createPanel(button), BorderLayout.EAST);
        f.add(createPanel(button), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(button);
        f.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(button);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JPanel createPanel(JButton b) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        final JTextField text = new JTextField();
        b.addActionListener(new UpdateHandler(text));
        panel.add(text);
        return panel;
    }

    private static class UpdateHandler extends AbstractAction {

        private JTextField text;
        private DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");

        public UpdateHandler(JTextField t) {
            super("update");
            t.setText(df.format(new Date()));
            this.text = t;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            text.setText(df.format(new Date()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```