# Is there a way to set the Ubuntu default focus button color in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu, gtk, jbutton

I am just trying to have some of my `JButtons` to be painted fully orange in addition to the orange border when they have focus. Instead, `setFocusPainted(true)` turns out to only paint the border:

[image]

Many applications seem to use the full orange buttons for focus, but I struggle to find the correct solution for this in Java Swing.

I have no problems implementing my own custom `JButtons` or whatever. But I would think there *should* be a simple setting for this, because I shouldn't have to go and find out the RGB color values which Ubuntu uses so I can comply with native UI stuff.

I want this:

[image]

Pressing tab changes the `JButton` to its normal color as it loses focus.

I am obviously using the specific System's LAF. I used `setFocusPainted(true)` and all (otherwise the orange border wouldn't be there). It is also possible to get this when using MigLayouts specified buttons (okbutton etc.):

[image]

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for the [`setDefaultButton()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html#setDefaultButton-javax.swing.JButton-) method of [`JRootPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html), shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7457102/230513), in concert with the [`GTKLookAndFeel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html).

```
java -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel …
```

[image]

Comment: @ChrisK: Glad it helped; the corresponding appearance is seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14947144/230513) in an earlier version of  `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel`.

Comment: Thanks, I have tested this on OSX and Windows as well and it's precisely what I was looking for. Guess I should have understood that this is Ubuntu's treatment of the root pane's "default button". I always thought it was just some specific focus highlighting.